# Embedded Flash not working in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome

So I have a flash site and I am curious why it is not working in Chrome. The site works great for Safari, Firefox, and IE. Just won't work in Chrome. Well below is the code and any help is necessary. Also can you explain why it doesn't work?

```
 <div id="flashContent">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="750" height="470" id="mariocoded" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="mariocoded.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />

                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mariocoded.swf" width="750" height="470">
                    <param name="movie" value="mariocoded.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />

                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />

                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
```

Comment: your problem looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844516/resizing-div-with-js-from-flash-makes-flash-appear-to-freeze-in-chrome/4846875#4846875

Comment: checked the linked to question and it wasn't similar really

Comment: so there can't be a problem with scaling? may i take a look at the site btw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two nested `<object>` tags instead of `<object>` and `<embed>`.  [Chrome, Safari and FF all use `<embed>`](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/13/embedding-flash#The_Object_Tag_and_the_Embed_Tag), so it's actually surprising the player runs in FF and Safari at all.

Answer (score 3):

replace all that code with just this single line of code and it should work in all browsers...

```
<embed src="mariocoded.swf" width="750" height="470" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem...if I took away the param name="movie" from the outer object it worked for me (but of course not in IE so you have to selectively show it for IE).  I think chrome gets confused and recognizes the movie parameter but instead of ignoring it, it decides that it just won't show anything.

Another interesting thing is that if you open up the developer tools for google chrome (using your original code) you can mouseover the html flashContent div and the flash file will appear.  It's like it's there underneath but the movie parameter screws it up.

Hope this helps.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Kevin you got it - If you inspect the flash element using Chrome's element inspector, edit as html and remove the name=movie it will display so the conditional comments should work wonders

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this, as i am also using Flash in Chrome but for that i have used Both as here

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="1000" height="250" id="FlashVars_AS2" align="middle">

                <param name="movie" value="MuShagPlayer.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="low" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
                <param name=FlashVars value="surl=http://www.mp3hungama.com/music/audio/Indian/Indian%20Movies/3G%20(2013)/songs/Kaise%20Bataaoon%20@%20Mp3HunGama.Com.mp3&waveform=${waveform}&tle=${songTitle}&sId=${songId}" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="MuShagPlayer.swf" width="1000" height="250">
                <param name="movie" value="MuShagPlayer.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="low" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
                <param name=FlashVars value="surl=http://www.mp3hungama.com/music/audio/Indian/Indian%20Movies/3G%20(2013)/songs/Kaise%20Bataaoon%20@%20Mp3HunGama.Com.mp3&waveform=${waveform}&tle=${songTitle}&sId=${songId}" />
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>

            </object>

        </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

May you can edit 
from:

```
<param name="play" value="true" />
```

became:

```
<param name="autoplay" value="true" />
```

i have try it and then successed.